# Symfony Unable to find template "" error only in Amazon Web Service

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, symfony, twig

I have a Symfony project running in Amazon Web Service. It has an option to generate a xlsx file to download (export data option). This option fail with the message:

> Unable to find template "" (looked into: / home / ubuntu / emilpa /
>   emilpa / app / Resources / views, / home / ubuntu / emilpa / emilpa /
>   vendor / symfony / symfony / src / Symfony / Bridge / Twig / Resources
>   / views / Form).

I do not understand, In my machine I can not reproduce this error because it is working fine.

Comment: is this should be like this https://prnt.sc/qyykw1

Comment: @Zeljka It is not the problem. In my local machine works fine

Comment: but do you really have 2 directories with the same name, because maybe something is wrong with def paths

Comment: @Zeljka This is the project path...I think that is not the problem. Local and production path are the same

Comment: Please, somebody can help us?? Regards